# Getting an error for could not convert string object cannot be interpreted as integer on Spotipy library

Tags: python, pandas, string, spotipy

This is my function code, and another parameter code above to get more data, and then now I am trying to gather all of this and create a dataset. The code in itself is working fine, and Im getting all the data output as well:

```
def download_playlist(id_playlist,n_songs):
 songs_id = []
 tracks = []
 col=[]

 for i in range(0,n_songs,100):
    playlist = spt.playlist_tracks(id_playlist,limit=100,offset=i)
    
    for songs in playlist['items']:
        songs_id.append(songs['track']['id'])

 counter = 1
 for ids in songs_id:
    
    time.sleep(.6)
    track,columns = get_songs_features(ids)
    tracks.append(track)
    col.append(columns)

    print(f"Song {counter} Added:")
    print(f"{track[0]} By {track[2]} from the album {track[1]}")
    clear_output(wait = True)
    counter+=1

 clear_output(wait = True)
 print("Music Downloaded!")

 return tracks,col
```

BUT WHEN I try to run this code to create the dataset:

```
 tracks,columns=download_playlist('playlist_id',number_of_songs)
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(tracks,columns=columns)
 df1.head()
```

My dataset is empty... how do I fix this?

Comment: The second argument to `download_playlist` has to be a number or a string that can be parsed as a number.  The string `'number_of_songs'` can't be converted to a number.

Comment: If that's the name of a variable, don't put it in quotes.

Comment: Thank you that worked! but now im getting this error:

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'columns' referenced before assignment

Comment: That can't be coming from the code posted above, it must be somewhere else. There are many questions about that error message, search for them to see how to resolve it.